# keyof only exist property

Tags: typescript, keyof

i have a next type

```
type Data = {
 foo: {
   foo_id: number;
 };
 bar: undefined;
 abc: {
   abc_id: number
 }
};
```

I need to get array of nested keys, if they exist, and ignore undefined values:
`'foo_id' | 'abc_id'[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive self-indexing [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Data = {
  foo: {
    foo_id: number;
  };
  bar: undefined;
  abc: {
    abc_id: number
  }
};

type NestedKeys<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? never :
                    T[K] extends object ? NestedKeys<T[K]> : K
}[keyof T];

type X = NestedKeys<Data>[];

const x: X = ['foo_id', 'abc_id'];
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUBmB7PALnS21wIH0BLAE2IDsBXAWwCMIAnAblIF8fsrOB2KN6NCDir0INAVDisAxsUxkFy6nShM2nPhn4YMoSFAByEAM7BZAaQggrAHgAqUCAA9b4q1DysAFYQSsAAfCgk6gDadlDSUADWjng4UK4AusSusRke3hC+UGISUjI0UAD8OhAAbpxQhKTqLa1kOXZ5Xj40fgHBoVUW1rY0Dk5uuRHEdobRySCp6Rk8JuDQABqRljb2ji7wiGHRK8ZKePQ2UJ7EW6jRAOT4eFoPADRQD4pKr6dAA)

Comment: Interesting, especially the `[keyof T`] in the end.